# create dataframe from map in spark java API

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use spark sql in java API, below simple stuff (copied from official guide: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html) would not make intelij happy.

It complains the `ClassTag` thing, which i do not know how to create it or let it automatically imported or something.

```
        List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        JavaRDD<Integer> distData = sc.parallelize(data);
```

I understand it wants to use 3 arguments

```
public <T> RDD<T> parallelize(final Seq<T> seq, final int numSlices, final ClassTag<T> evidence$1) {
```

but how can i get this `evidence$1` thing?
the official example did not have the argument either

Please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to look into the source code of the example came with the official guideline.
and turns out it needs to create java spark context
I got my one working after I used the example from the guide's source code.

```
import scala.Tuple2;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

List<Tuple2<String, String>> data =
        Arrays.asList(
                new Tuple2<>("key1","value1")
                , new Tuple2<>("key2", "value2")
        );

JavaPairRDD<String, String> dataRdd = jsc.parallelizePairs(data);
```